# bash storing array variables in rotation

Tags: bash, scripts

My objective is store values in array , as below:

```
arr[0]=apple
arr[1]=banana
arr[2]=orange
arr[3]=grapes
arr[4]=apple
arr[5]=banana
arr[6]=orange
arr[7]=grapes
arr[8]=apple
arr[9]=banana
```

I can achieve above expected output using the below script ,

But Want to know is there any optimized way /procedure to achieve this.

--- Start -----

```
#!/bin/bash

#####################################
for((a=0;a<=100;a+=4))
    do
       echo ""
       arr[$a]="apple"
done
######################################


#####################################
for((b=1;b<=105;b+=4))
    do
       echo ""
       arr[$b]="banana"
done
######################################


#####################################
for((c=2;c<=106;c+=4))
    do
       echo ""
       arr[$c]="orange"
done
######################################


#####################################
for((d=3;d<=107;d+=4))
    do
       echo ""
       arr[$d]="grapes"
done
######################################




for((i=0;i<=9;i+=1))
    do
       echo ""
       y=${arr[$i]}
echo $y
    done
```

---end -------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to set an array with the four values you want to cycle through, and then use the % (modulo) operator in your for loop to determine which of the four values to assign to arr[$a]

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

values=("apple", "banana", "orange", "grape")

#####################################
for((a=0;a<=100;a++))
  do
    arr[$a]=${values[$a % 4]}
done
######################################

for((i=0;i<=9;i++))
  do
    echo ${arr[$i]}
done
```

Comment: cool this worked